# How to filter fake names with TFLearn

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, tflearn

I am trying to train a neural network with a list of names and then have it give me a probability that a user input name is real.

Example: asldfkjbwlkj would have a very low probability of being a real name.

**Thoughts:**

1. Could I train a Generative Neural Network and use some sort of accuracy test on a single user input name?
2. I could also feed the list of names to a Deep Neural Network as well as some randomly generated characters with [1,0], and [0,1] respectively but I haven't been able to find any really good examples on how to vectorize a list of words. Or if this method would even work.

Here is one example I've been looking at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tflearn/tflearn/master/examples/nlp/lstm_generator_cityname.py

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sounds like you're in the right direction.
You can train a [char-rnn](https://www.google.com/search?q=char+rnn+tensorflow)  generative model.

During inference (test time), you can feed it with a username, and evaluate the probability score of that username. By setting a threshold for the probability score, you can select between fake or real usernames.

During training, you should train your model with a dataset of real usernames

Comment: So train it with a set of real usernames. I can do that. How exactly do you test a generative model, do I just train it, save it. Then load it and fit again for a single username and get the accuracy of it? There is no predict available for Generative models in TFLearn.

Comment: Conceptually yes, in generative models. I don't know how this API works in TFlearn.

Comment: @CameronJohnson, if you found my answer useful, please up vote or accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm going to do some more testing in the AM and I will probably accept it. I'm not 100% sure this is going to work but I see what you are thinking. My reputation is low still but I just upvoted. Thanks for your input either way.

Comment: This is definitely a classification problem. Been looking into this for awhile now. Generative just isn't the way to do it. Just fyi.